# Why does $\sqrt{\cos x+1} = \sqrt{2}\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

While playing around with equations on desmos, I noticed that:

$$\sqrt{\cos x+1} = \sqrt{2}\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|$$

which may suggests an connection between the square root of a cosine function and its absolute function evaluation. Is this something that is known and/or meaningful? Has this been used for any significant proof?

Comment: I just learned that it comes from the half-angle identities, but I am leaving the question up in case anyone has any interesting thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very meaningful. Just thinking about the fact that you can represent the square or squareroot of $cos(x)$ as terms of linear $sin(x/2)$ or $cos(x/2)$ looks a pretty strong property.

For example, it helps **a lot** when you are trying to solve $\int cos^2(x) \, dx$ or $\int \sqrt{cos(x)} \, dx$.

Search on Google about these integrations with and without using the identity mentioned (or give a try by yourself if you're familiar with calculus), you'll see how difficult these problems can turn :)

Answer (score 3):

The double angle formula gives $$\cos(2u) = \cos^2(u) - \sin^2(u) = 2\cos^2(u) -1.$$
Thus,
$$\cos(2u)+1 = 2\cos^2(u).$$

Take square roots and set $x=2u$.

Comment: Is the connection meaningful in any way?

Comment: @Josue What does "meaningful" mean? It is a well known, very useful formula for calculations. It was known to Ptolemy and other greek geometers, as well as to Indian astronomers.

Comment: I should have phrased it differently. I meant to say if it had been used on any major proof. But, I understand its significance to calculations now. Thanks for answering the question